# How to access the each string characters from TextEditingController and provide the values to each characters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to access the each characters of TextEditing Controller and provide values to each characters in Flutter. For example, I had written Everest in Textediting field, I want to access each characters E,v,e,r,e,s,t and provide E=1, v=1, e=1, r=1, e=1, s=1, t=1. I want to assign the values like this and do some calculation?

I tried by doing controller.text[0] which provide me the value of first index but when i try to assign value (controller.text[0]=1.toString()) the [0] shows error and can't assign the value?

Comment: Hi, I'm unsure what you mean by "provide values to each character." Could you provide more information or context about what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to store the values of each character in a separate variable or data structure, or are you trying to modify the actual characters in the TextEditingController? 

Also, what do you mean by "do some calculation"? Could you provide more details about what calculation you want to perform and how the values of the characters will be used in the estimate?

Comment: Suppose there is textediting controller which value is shown on TextformField and controller retrieve the value. For example, when I type LONDON on TextFormField,then I want to assign integer value to each characters of Textformfield( L = 1, O =2, N=1, D=0, N=1. I am not able to provide value. I want to know how can i assign integer values to the textformfield each characters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.